# Proper JSON format for highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts

I have a mysql db feeding pairs to my highcharts.  It is feeding timestamp and sensor values for a pH meter.  When I load the graph I get the tool tip showing the timestamp and sensor value but as it feeds continuously from the database the tooltip shows undefined as my timestamp, yet the array I built has it there.  I want to be specific as possible.  I think that I am building my json strings incorrectly and that is why the highcharts has no idea what to do with it.

Here is my callback to the php page:

```
events: {
    load: function() {
        var chart = this;
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function() {                                    
            $.getJSON("php/dataPhIncremental.php", function(data) {
                // Only add data points if the latest date in the DB is different
                if (!(chart.yAxis[0].dataMax == data[0].data[0])) {
                    $(chart.series).each(function(i, series) {
                        console.log(data[0]);
                        series.addPoint([data[0].timestamp[0], data[0].data[0]]);

                    }); 
                } 
                else {
                    console.log("did not write point"+ oldPoint + "   " + data[0].data);
                }
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
```

thought getJSON would go to the php page and pick up the json string and let highcharts do what it wants with it.  I was wrong.

Sample of my php json return object:

```
[{"name":"pH","data":[4.76],"timestamp":["2015-12-23 12:31:42"]}]
```

This is for the incremental callback.  The initial string holds 10 pairs.

Comment: `"2015-12-23 12:31:42"` is not a timestamp. You are providing strings, when Highcharts expects timestamps in milliseconds for `datetime` axis.

Comment: Is this the only problem you see? Can you link me to some documentation on how to get this working?  And if your idea is correct then why does the initial load show the timestamps that I am providing in this incorrect format?

Answer (score 0):

try using a date type:

```
                    console.log(data[0]);
                    d = new Date(data[0].timestamp[0]);
                    series.addPoint(d, data[0].data[0]);
```

Try this for your xAxis:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e %b', this.value*1000); // milliseconds not seconds
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: this seems like its on the right track but now in my tooltip I get invalid date.

Comment: Do you have tooltip xDateFormat defined ?  Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/xdateformat/

Comment: Also, is your  xAxis defined as datetime? 
      xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
      },

Comment: OK, so I think what is going on is that in my tooltip code I have defined it as part of the json return string of the initial load.

`
     xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime' 
     },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: { text: null }
        },

        tooltip: {
     xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
     formatter: function() {
      console.log(json);
             return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b>     <br/>'+
             new Date(json[0].timestamp[this.x]) +': '+ this.y;
     }
        }`

how can I write it so that it uses the initial load then the new points?

Comment: Are you saying that the additional points loaded after the initial load have a differently formatted tooltip ?

Comment: No the only difference is that the php page that collects the initial load uses limit 100 in the mysql query - The php page that collects the latest value uses limit 1 in the mysql query.  The objects/arrays are all the same.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please elaborate on "how can I write it so that it uses the initial load then the new points?"

Comment: Ok so what I want to do is have the initial query populate the table's xAxis with timestamps and the tooltip should show the timestamp as well as the actual value. After the initial 100 load I want the chart to reach out to another php page that returns the latest point added to the database.  This should then be displayed on the graph, the xAxis should show another value - the latest timestamp - and the tooltip for the new point should show the timestamp as well as the new value. Right now the caption only shows the new value. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: Got it.  The tooltip for every point is correct for the initial load,  points added after the initial load do not have the correctly formatted tooltip and are actually missing the date time stamp.  Is that right?

Comment: yes sir that is exactly the case. Also, the xAxis shows no timestamp at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98844/discussion-between-jared-and-vinnyguitara).